# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Sensor.add error in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am getting the below exception when I try to create a kafka streams instance.
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Sensor.add(Lorg/apache/kafka/common/MetricName;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/metrics/MeasurableStat;)Z
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.<init>(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$StreamsMetricsThreadImpl.<init>(StreamThread.java:525)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.create(StreamThread.java:618)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:706)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:624)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:534)`

I am trying to run the WordCountDemo scala example in intellij but unable to do so. I have `org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-scala_2.11:2.1.0` and `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.0.2` dependencies included in my project and see the jars imported.

Comment: You will need same client version `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.1.0` that matches KafkaStreams version.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was already found in the comments by @Matthias

> You will need same client version org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.1.0 that matches KafkaStreams version

This was confirmed to work for the asker.